# NUnit retry dynamic attribute

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Hello I want to pass the number of retries dynamically from app.config value.

The app.config has the following line:

```xml
<add key="retryTest" value="3"/>
```

And I have defined this variable:

```
public static readonly int numberOfRetries = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["retryTest"]);
```

Finally I would like to pass that variable as a parameter to Retry NUnit attribute:

```cs
[Test, Retry(numberOfRetries)]
public void Test()
{
    //.... 
}
```

But I get the following error:

> "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter
>   type"

How can I dynamically pass that value?

Comment: Good question, first I assumed this could be done with the `TestCaseSource`-attribute where you can dynamically inject test-*data*. However this doesn´t seem to work for test-*parameters*. From the source-code I couldn´t find any way to dynamically add parameters to the test.

Comment: Retry is not a parameter of the TestAttribute, it's a separate attribute. If it were a parameter, the syntax would be `[Test(Retry=3)]` !!Invalid!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I am not fully aware of the [`RetryAttribute`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/4e2dc9d1acf30040a74e7152f11cb4d0ab5f2da1/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/RetryAttribute.cs). One possible way of achieving the desired functionality would be to extend its current functionality.

```
/// <summary>
/// RetryDynamicAttribute may be applied to test case in order
/// to run it multiple times based on app setting.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class RetryDynamicAttribute : RetryAttribute {
    private const int DEFAULT_TRIES = 1;
    static Lazy<int> numberOfRetries = new Lazy<int>(() => {
        int count = 0;
        return int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["retryTest"], out count) ? count : DEFAULT_TRIES;
    });

    public RetryDynamicAttribute() :
        base(numberOfRetries.Value) {
    }
}
```

And then apply the custom attribute.

```
[Test]
[RetryDynamic]
public void Test() {
    //.... 
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to go.

Comment: It works fine! Thank you. But just realised that when it gets a timeout error it doesn´t work. Any way to update that?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of work around, but you can use `TestCaseSource` attribute to create data driven test that will run `numberOfRetries` times

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("GetNum")]
public void Test(int testNum)
{
}

private IEnumerable GetNum
{
    get
    {
        int numberOfRetries = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["retryTest"]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRetries; ++i)
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In test explorer you will see `Test(1)`, `Test(2)`, `Test(3)`.

Comment: mmm thank you but I am not able to make this code work... :(

Comment: @joudaon what is the problem?

Comment: Clever... the retry attribute is actually a sort of degenerate test case source. :-)

Comment: @Guy the error I get is: The sourceName specified on a TestCaseSourceAttribute must refer to a static field, property or method

Comment: Need to update "private IEnumerable GetNum" to "private static IEnumerable GetNum". Also  That would work for repeat, really you are not retrying in this way.